# Meaning(s) of 덮치다?

Tags: vocabulary, meaning

I'm wondering if somebody could give me a comprehensive definition of the word 덮치다? I figured it's to do with attacking / invading, but if someone could give me a concise definition that would be great. Example sentences would be amazing too! Haha. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

덮다 means to cover over something, and 치다 means to attack/hit/aggressively charge. So, 덮치다 means to attack and press down (or attack with such overwhelming power). Also can be used to describe disasters like tsunami, hurricane, and avalanche, and non-physical crisis or concepts, such as economic depression, corruption scandal, etc. It is also a slang which means to forcefully or dominatingly have sex (but not necessarily a rape).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comprehensive definition you provided!